# How can I identify a stream as fit for mikveh?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

I'm trying to understand how to identify a stream as a mikveh.  Clearly the stream has to flow.  But what sources of the stream are permitted:  drainage basin (a.k.a watershed), aquifer, and others?

Comment: You can get few informations [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68854/9215)

Comment: Mikveh for nidda or kelim or for tevilat Ezra?

Comment: general purpose

Comment: "Clearly the stream has to flow." Why is that clear?

Comment: From previous answers, a spring has to be 'living water', from a spring.  If its not running, then it's a lake, which is not valid, right?

Comment: @eter I don't know where you saw that here, but it's definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 162:12](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur162.html#12).

The source of a Mikvah of flowing water must be a spring. Rainwater is only kosher for a mikvah when it is standing still. (The halacha discusses a mixture of the two).

Therefore, if the source of the flowing water is only rain or melted snow, it would not be good for a mikvah. It it was a mixture of spring water and rain/melted snow, it would only be acceptable in extreme circumstances, as detailed in that Halacha.